# Coherence exception for Unknow user type for JAVA API class

Tags: java, oracle-coherence

After implemented annotation based POF Serialization in Coherence POC,
I am getting following exception:

```
unknown user type: java.lang.Class
```

Whatever the classes I am using, I added those names inside my custom pof config file and also added inbuilt pof config.
Still somehow I am getting above exception.
Could you please explain these.
Here one more doubt is, this class belongs to JAVA api, so how to add this type of class to custom pof config file.

Stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown user type: java.lang.Class
    at com.tangosol.io.pof.ConfigurablePofContext.getUserTypeIdentifier(ConfigurablePofContext.java:438)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your pof-config.xml file ?

Comment: Hi Thorynque, thanks for quick reply. My custom pof having bunch of classes. In my configuration one of my class is using Java.lang.class, so i how i need to include that type in my custom config. Apart from that custom config is fine.

Comment: I need the part of the code where you put your object in coherence